# Finding the exact volume of a solid with y=5sqrtx, x=0, y=6

Tags: calculus, volume, solid-of-revolution

I just started Calculus 2 recently and while things were running smoothly, I am having trouble with volumes.

At first I tried with this question the Vertical Revolution formula:

2π 0to6 (bounds) (5sqrtx)(6)dx, multiplying and integrating for 20x^3/2 and plugging in 6, since 0 is 0, but then I got 293.9387, which wasn't right.

I appreciate any help, and I can provide any more information if needed, thank you. Sorry if the formatting is off.

Comment: Please use MathJax to format equations.

Comment: Alright I will try to figure out how to use that, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that :
$$y=5\sqrt{x}$$
$$y^2=25x$$
$$\frac{y^2}{25}=x$$
$$x=\frac{y^2}{25}$$
$$f(y)=\frac{y^2}{25}$$

Use the formula :
$$V=\pi \int _a^b\left(f\left(y\right)\right)^2\:dy$$
$$V=\pi \int _0^6\left(\frac{y^2}{25}\right)^2\:dy\:$$
$$V=\pi \int _0^6\left(\frac{y^4}{625}\right)\:dy\:$$
$$V=\pi \left[\frac{y^5}{3125}\right]_{0\:}^6$$
$$V=\frac{7776\pi }{3125}$$

Comment: WOW! Thank you so much! I had tried using that method as well and see that when using that method I was never multiplying the 5 in the beginning!

Comment: You are welcome. I would be appreciate if you can upvote my answer.

Comment: It says I need 15 reputation to do so, so as soon as I get there I certainly will!